# PropertyInfo.GetValue returned object is not seen as null by visual studio / resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, warnings

I'm retrieving the value of a property by calling the GetValue like so:

```
//have T tObj;
var sExpr = s.Body as MemberExpression;
var sProp = typeof(T).GetProperty(sExpr.Member.Name);
var sVal = dProp.GetValue(tObj, null);
```

For some reason sVal is never considered to be null by the compiler/resharper (i'm not sure which one is showing the warning).  I don't get possible null reference warnings at design time. If I create a condition like `if(sVal == null)` I'll get a design time warning that the expression is always false.

sVal is just an object, and objects can be null.  I don't think GetValue guarantees never to return null.  What's going on?

Comment: what warning does look like ?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program which gives a warning. I strongly suspect it's not the code you think it is.

Comment: Probably because that first `var sExpr = s.Body as MemberExpression;` is the one that R# is recognizing as possibly being null.

Comment: Also, totally OT, but: You can access the PropertyInfo directly from sExpr by doing `(PropertyInfo)sExpr.Member`. Should save some cycles by avoiding reflection

Answer (score 1):

John Skeet was right.  I was checking for null after working with the variable. I rearranged my code to do the null check BEFORE working with the variable and the problem went away.  What strange is that I didn't get a null reference warning before and I should have.